# HTML audio: accessing MP3 chapter markers

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I was hoping to update my web-based audio player to include support for MP3 chapter markers, but I can't find anything in the documentation for dealing with this. Is this even possible to do?

Comment: Yes, it is, though it will require somewhat near a truckload of js to make a custom MP3 player. Potentially helpful link: https://imajineweb.com/javascriptaudioplayer/

Comment: An alternative, however, is to add a few buttons that change the position of the playback to a certain time. Potentially helpful link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29593733/i-want-to-stop-skip-30-seconds-on-audio-in-html